# How to find records ONLY having multiple rows in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Customers have accounts with us for their vehicles. Some accounts have multiple vehicles.

I would like to create a report of accounts ONLY with multiple vehicles (i.e. Multiple AccountIDs and Licence Plate numbers.)

Table Account A
Table Plate P
A.AccountId = P.AccountId

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,A.AccountId
      ,P.LicPlateNo

FROM Account A
INNER JOIN Plate P ON A.AccountId = P.AccountId

WHERE A.RegDate > '2017-01-01'
  AND (Select Count(P.LicPlateNo) GROUP BY A.AccountNumber) > 1
   -- HAVING Count(P.LicPlateNo) > 1 ????

ORDER BY A.AccountNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use having directly

```
    SELECT A.AccountNumber
          ,A.AccountId
          ,P.LicPlateNo

    FROM Account A
    INNER JOIN Plate P ON A.AccountId = P.AccountId
    WHERE A.RegDate > '2017-01-01'
    GROUP BY A.AccountNumber
    HAVING Count(P.LicPlateNo) > 1
    ORDER BY A.AccountNumber
```

Comment: Gives me a Syntax error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: answer  updated .. wrong sequence in having and group by

Answer (score 1):

You got it almost .. need to use `group by` and `having` condition like

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,A.AccountId
      ,P.LicPlateNo

FROM Account A
INNER JOIN (
SELECT LicPlateNo, AccountId
FROM Plate 
GROUP BY AccountId
HAVING Count(LicPlateNo) > 1 ) P
ON A.AccountId = P.AccountId
WHERE A.RegDate > '2017-01-01'
ORDER BY A.AccountNumber
```

Comment: This didn't quite work because I need it to group by Account Number not Account ID. Some Account Numbers have multiple Account IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `count() over()`

```
SELECT AccountNumber
      ,AccountId
      ,LicPlateNo
FROM (
    SELECT A.AccountNumber
          ,A.AccountId
          ,P.LicPlateNo
          ,cnt = count(P.LicPlateNo) over(partition by P.AccountId)
    FROM Account A
    INNER JOIN Plate P ON A.AccountId = P.AccountId
    WHERE A.RegDate > '2017-01-01'
) t
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY AccountNumber
```